# Include Streams module via CDN

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I'm new to Mithrill v1.0.0, And now I have problem with it. In previous version, I can use `m.prop()` for setter/getter variable. In new version, it replace with Streams module.

In the Mithrill docs say :

> Streams are NOT bundled with Mithril's core distribution. To include
>   the Streams module, use:
>
> ```
> var Stream = require("mithril/stream")
> ```

And my problem is I don't know how to include that. I use mithrill via CDN. When I try to use `prop()` or `stream()` directly, It give me error that function is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/stream/stream.js"></script>
```

It'll be available as `window.stream`.

Comment: Note that it will be available on `m.stream` if mithril is already loaded on the page.